# C++ - Can a template template parameter be of a variable or function?

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, c++14, iso

I'm still trying to fully understand templates. I see them as special types.

Recently I was reading about template template parameters of classes and
I'm wondering if it it is possible to have a template template parameter of function or variable and not only of class? Something like this:

```
template<typename T> void func(T); //template of function 'func'

template<int a> double var = a; //template of variable 'var'

template<template<typename> void templ_param() = func, //parameter template of function

template<int> double templ_param_0 = var //parameter template of variable

> void func1();
```

EDIT: If not why and what is the alternative?

Comment: You have your declarations and definitions mixed up. What is template<int>?

Comment: I guess a template with single param of type 'int'?

Comment: You guessed wrong. There is no such thing

Comment: `template <typename T> 
class A
{
 T var;
}; `  and `A<int> myObj`

Comment: @Golazo, There sure is, and it's really the basis for TMP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm wondering if it it is possible to have a template template parameter of function

No, you cannot. Your example code snippet won't work.

```
template <template <typename T>> void templ_param() = func,
```

A template template parameter must be a class template or an alias template.

From the C++ standard:

> **14.3.3 Template template arugments**
>
> 1 A *template-argument* for a template *template-parameter* shall be the name of a class template or an alias template, expressed as *id-expression*.

Answer (score 1):

No, template template parameters may be only types.

[temp.param]/1 describes template parameter syntax as follows:

> *template-parameter:*
>
> - *type-parameter*
> - *parameter-declaration*
>
> *type-parameter:*
>
> - *type-parameter-key `...`<sub>opt</sub> identifier<sub>opt</sub>*
> - *type-parameter-key identifier<sub>opt</sub>*`=` *type-id*
> - `template <` *template-parameter-list* `>` *type-parameter-key* `...`*<sub>opt</sub> identifier<sub>opt</sub>*
> - `template <` *template-parameter-list* `>` *type-parameter-key* *identifier<sub>opt</sub>*`=` *id-expression*
>
> *type-parameter-key:*
>
> - `class`
> - `typename`

So template template parameters are put into category of type-parameters, and indeed, their declaration must contain either `class` or `typename` after `template<...>`

As an alternative you can wrap template functions and variables into classes:

```
template <typename T>
struct FuncWrapper {
    static void func(T t) {
        std::cout << "in func " << t << std::endl;
    }
};

template <int a>
struct VarWrapper {
    static constexpr double var = a;
};

template<
    template <typename T> class FW = FuncWrapper,
    template <int> class VW = VarWrapper> 
void func1() {
    FW<int>::func(VW<42>::var);
}

int main() {
    func1<>();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why and if there is a possible alternative?

Comment: About why - I think it's better ask someone from the ISO committee, but even if you do, I think the answer will be "there was no proposal about that". Regarding the alternative - for example you can create a template class with static function/variable.

Comment: @FISOCPP I updated my answer with possible alternative