# How can I use template template type as an function argument?

Tags: c++

I want to implement the following code:

```
template <int i>
void f() {
    ...
}
template <template <int i> typename Func>
void g(Func func, int i) {
    if (i == 0) func<0>();
    else if (i == 1) func<1>();
    else if (i == 2) func<2>();
    else assert(false);
}
int main() {
    g(f, 0);
}
```

However, this code can not be compiled. It says "error: argument list for template template parameter "Func" is missing". I don't know how to fix it. Thank you very much!

Comment: it's not clear what you want to achieve. template template is probably not what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templates can be used as arguments to templates, but they cannot be used as arguments to functions. Hence the error; when you tried to use a template name (`Func`) as the type of a function parameter, the compiler complained that a template name by itself is not enough. A template argument list is needed to get a type out of the template, and only then can it be the type of a function parameter.

It looks like you are trying to replicate the template parameter as a function parameter. Don't do that. Use the template parameter directly.

```
template <template<int> typename Func>
void g(int i) {
    if (i == 0) Func<0>();
    else if (i == 1) Func<1>();
    else if (i == 2) Func<2>();
    else assert(false);
}
```

However, there is a further problem with your setup. As suggested by the `typename` keyword, a template template argument cannot be a function template. **So this does not work.**
See [Can a template template parameter be of a variable or function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29219576/c-can-a-template-template-parameter-be-of-a-variable-or-function)

---

An alternative (brought up by the OP) might be to use a class template and `operator()`. One caveat is that `operator()` cannot be static, so there is another syntactical change to `g`.

```
template <template<int> typename Func>
void g(int i) {
    if (i == 0) Func<0>{}();      // <
    else if (i == 1) Func<1>{}(); // < -- Invoke operator() on a temporary
    else if (i == 2) Func<2>{}(); // <
    else assert(false);
}
```

Given a class template `f`, this could be invoked via `g<f>(0)`.

Comment: Thank you! If I use a class and overload the operator (), should the above code work?

Comment: @zbh2047 There are some caveats, but basically yes. I've added to my answer.